# Is "moral implication appropriate here?

Tags: meaning

Now I am going to trace back this historical process in order to further illuminate on the moral implications of “bonds” and“constants”.

The context is Chinese ethics. "bonds" and "constants" have their own meaning , but when used in the domain of morality, they have many special meanings.Through a research into the history, these meanings will become clearer. So which word shall I use?

Answer (score 2):

The phrase **moral implication** is more useful when referring to the results or significance of an action with respect to morality.

For example, the **moral implications** of killing during war.

The above example doesn't mean we're talking about the word 'kill' having a different *meaning* in the 'domain of morality'. It means we're talking about the morality around the *action* of killing during war.

I assume that in your case, you are talking about certain kanjis having special morality related meanings? If that's what you're trying to convey, then a better construction might be:

> I am going to trace the history / origin of the morality specific readings of the kanji for "bonds" and "constant".

(If this is not what you're trying to convey, could you add some clarifications here, please?)

Note: In your provided sentence, there's another item to note. One seeks to "shed further illumination on something" or "further illuminate something". Not "further illuminate *on* something".